# php explode function to get each line as as a string of a textarea

Tags: php

I have a textarea in the page and I need to get each line as a string and need to store them in DB.

```
<textarea id="address" name="invoice_address_to" class="form-control input-noshow" rows="6" cols="35">
Some Company
Address 1
Address 2
Zipcode State
Country
                    </textarea>
```

I know that explode function will help me to do this but can't process it. I have done the following code:

echo (explode("/n/r",'address'));

I want to store each line in an array and want to store each array values into the DB. My concern is with splitting the textarea values into arrays for each line.

Comment: show your effort or some error you are getting??

Comment: what is the exact question you are facing? There is just too much here. We can help with problems, but won't do your homework. Is your problem the exploding? The storing in a db? The receiving the text in PHP ?

Comment: @nl-x my question here is how to split the textarea values into arrays on each line...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What you should do is have a text field for each line.

Comment: First of all first argument in explode should looks `"\n\r"`, but it's better idea to use `PHP_EOL` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This breaks the each new line into an array, then puts each element of the array into it's own variable. Of course you will need to validate before DB insertion to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php

list($company, $addr_1, $addr2, $zipcode, $country) = explode("\n", $_POST['invoice_address_to']);

?>
```

Comment: thanks this is the solution am looking for...and sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: No problem! Mark me as the correct answer please ;)

Answer (score 0):

You say you have done:

```
echo (explode("/n/r",'address'));
```

Here are 3 problems:

- `explode()` returns an array that you cannot echo as such. You could try using `print_r()` instead of `echo`.
- you are exploding using `/n/r` but what you need to do is use `\n` or `\r\n`, as that is the line separator used in the browsers sending the data. And notice the `\` vs `/`.
- You are using the string `address`. But what you want to use is a variable like `$_REQUEST['address']`